# Transition matrix inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, markov-chains

If you have a Markov chain, such that

$x_i A = x_{i+1}$,

is it true that:

$x_i = x_{i+1} A^{-1}$

Further, in the strange case where $A$ may be singular, is it appropriate to compute the Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse to get an approximate answer?

Thanks!

Comment: Sure, just multiply both sides by $A^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an earlier question, you asked about a Markov chain for which all rows of the transition matrix are the same. Clearly, that is a singular case. So in that *particular* singular case, the transition matrix would be of no use in approximating the state at the previous step.

Comment: Hi. Yes, but would the Moore-Penrose inverse not tell you anything?

Comment: In the case where the transition matrix has all rows the same, the steps are independent, so it seems to me nothing can help with approximation. Reworded my answer for clarity.

Comment: @ThomasMoore: not much, just how one dimension of the space changed. Not anything about how all the 0-eigenvalued ones were.

Comment: Analogous: I roll a fair die 10 times independently. What info about the 9th roll can be gained from the 10th? After some thought, I guess there is **one** less interesting kind of transition matrix from a probability point of view: the $n \times n$ identity (1's on the diagonal); a chain with no movement at all.

Comment: Hi @BruceET thank you for your very helpful comments and answers! Very enlightening.